# Print a pyramid/triangle using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pyramidMaxSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter numbers:");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int[] nums = new int[n];
            nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
                System.out.print(nums[i]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

This is my code.I can't seem to be able to get the desired output,which in turn does not allow me to finish my task.I want to print a pyramid/triangle using the standart input.From this input:

```
5
5 
10 20
1 3 1
99 20 7 40
5 15 25 30 35
```

I need to get this output

```
        5      
      10  20     
    1    3   1   
  99  20   7  40
 5   15  25  30  35
```

My result is as follows:

```
5 
 10 10 
 20 20 20 
 1 1 1 1 
 3 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Input all the numbers first, then build the pyramid.

Comment: that didnt seem to fix it,but then again I could have done something other than what you told me.I just have to move the int[] nums = new int[n];
 nums[i] = sc.nextInt(); out of the loop or?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops: one to input the numbers and one to print the pyramid.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // Get number of rows
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numRows = sc.nextInt();

    // Get all the numbers
    System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
    int numNumbers = numRows * (numRows + 1) / 2;
    int [] numbers = new int[numNumbers];
    for (int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
        numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    // Print the pyramid
    for( ..... Leaving this blank as this looks like homework...) {
    }
```